# TableLayout with ImageView inside

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and learning yet. I am trying to make my activity layout something like below image.
[image]

I thought to use TableLayout for same like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#ed8404">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_2"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#ed8404">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/row_4"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But I am not able to fix proper height on all images. Its looking something like this image.

[image]

Let me know if someone can help me for solve the issue. I want all images fit to view and with same height. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have more elements than can fit on the screen you have to use `RecyclerView` (with different `ViewHolder`s).

If you have fixed number of elements you can use `LinearLayout` to reduce nesting level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#F0F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#0FF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#FF0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#0F0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#F00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

For which you can expect output:
[image: layout]